# Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

Tags: wp-admin, login, capabilities

I have a big problem for a week I try to login in WordPress as administrator and I get a blank screen with this message "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page".

I have created a new admin user since PhpMyAdmin and the message continues to appear. I have removed and disabled all plugins and `wp_capabilities -> "a: 1: {s: 13:" administrator "; b: 1;}"` and `wp_user_level -> 10`. I also have no uppercase prefix everything is in lower case.

Someone can help me, please!!

Comment: Are you using any security plugins? Those can sometimes lock down access. Try accessing the login page directly by pointing the browser to `wp-login.php`

Comment: The serialized `wp_capabilities` array is not in the correct format. It should be `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`